# crossing 240 V traces on both top and bottom sides of a 2 layer PCB

Tags: pcb-design, mains, high-voltage, clearance, creepage

My situation is the same as the crossings encircled in white from [Can I place 220V Live traces on top and bottom of PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/341514/can-i-place-220v-live-traces-on-top-and-bottom-of-pcb)

> Therefore, running Line traces on the top layer and Neutral traces on
>   the bottom is fine.

The quote above from the first answer makes it unclear to me whether the same holds  true for Live-Live and Neutral-Neutral crossings. Are they still fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those cases the voltage difference will be same or less so it's also good.

Remember FR4 is good for over 10kV per mm (in the second answer), so low voltage mains circuits (<1kV) are perfectly fine across the thickness of the pcb (which is typically 1.6mm)

Comment: care need to be taken about vias, thru holes ?

Comment: @Hasanalattar that's another issue worth its own topic. I take due dilligence to clearance and creepage distances... until I hit my TO-220 triac.

Comment: pads (that is, exposed metal) mostly. The solder mask will help with vias. but yeah all holes make a shorter path from top to bottom.